# Como empilhar vários data frames no R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho 5 data frames no R com as mesmas colunas. Preciso agrupá-los em um único data.frame, qual comando devo usar?

Os nomes dos arquivos são: analise10, analise20, analise30, analise40, analise50.

Comment: `Reduce(rbind, list(df1, df2, df3))`.

Comment: Os nomes dos dataframes têm alguma coisa em comum? Se sim pode editar a pergunta com um exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Vou supor que os dataframes têm nomes com algo em comum, neste caso:

1. Começam com `"analise"`;
2. Terminam em números.

Então uma combinação de `ls/mget` pode automatizar a criação de uma lista a ser passada a `Reduce`.

```
df_names <- ls(pattern = "^analise\\d+$")
df_list <- mget(df_names)
Reduce(rbind, df_list)
             X          Y A
#1  -1.20706575  0.5060559 a
#2   0.27742924 -0.5747400 b
#3   1.08444118 -0.5466319 c
#4  -2.34569770 -0.5644520 d
#5   0.42912469 -0.8900378 e
#6  -0.47719270 -0.1102855 k
#7  -0.99838644 -0.5110095 l
#8  -0.77625389 -0.9111954 m
#9   0.06445882 -0.8371717 n
#10  0.95949406  2.4158352 o
#11  0.13408822 -1.4482049 u
#12 -0.49068590  0.5747557 v
#13 -0.44054787 -1.0236557 w
#14  0.45958944 -0.0151383 x
#15 -0.69372025 -0.9359486 y
```

**Código para criar os dados.**

```
set.seed(1234)
analise10 <- data.frame(X = rnorm(5), Y = rnorm(5), A = sample(letters, 5, TRUE))
analise20 <- data.frame(X = rnorm(5), Y = rnorm(5), A = sample(letters, 5, TRUE))
analise30 <- data.frame(X = rnorm(5), Y = rnorm(5), A = sample(letters, 5, TRUE))
analise40 <- data.frame(X = rnorm(5), Y = rnorm(5), A = sample(letters, 5, TRUE))
analise50 <- data.frame(X = rnorm(5), Y = rnorm(5), A = sample(letters, 5, TRUE))
```